# Listing only the particular data value in Tbgridview of yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii-extensions

I have an attribute, idC, which may contain any positive integer number. 
So, If idC has values like 2,3, and so on such that 3 comes 4 times and 2 comes 2 times.
Now, I want to list out data values with only idC=3 for one page 
and idC=2 for another page and so on.
But how to do this.

Here is the listing code:

```php
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'Subjects-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'template'=>'{summary}{items}{pager}',
    'columns'=>array(
        array('header'=>'<a>S.N.</a>',
            'value'=>'$data->id_subjects',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'70px'),
        ),
        'idC=$idC',
        array(
            'header'=>'<a>Subject</a>',
            'value'=>'$data->subject',
        ),
        'staff_type',
       'sub_subject',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'header'=>'<a>Actions</a>',
            'template' => '{view} {update}',
            'buttons' => array(

                'view' => array(
                    'label'=> 'View',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small view'
                    )                ),

            'update' => array(
                'label' => 'Update',
                'options' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-small update'
                )
            ),

            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
        )
    ),
)); ?>
```

and here's the view page.
[image]

Comment: Probably I didn't fully understand your question, but you can do next:
1. order by idC
2. filter by idC

Comment: Never mind, I did a silly mistake by making all the model's attributes to safe. Now, it's okay. Thanks though.